# how to solve sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Tags: python, nlp

Im trying to do some POS_Tagging using nltk (code below) and im running into the above issue when i try to write to a new file. if i run `#fout.write("\n".join(tagged))`this then it says the above error and totry and solve that when i run `#fout.write(str.join(tagged))` this it says `'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'`

The text file is locally stored and is relatively large

```
from pathlib import Path
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as wt
import nltk
import pprint

output_dir = Path ("\\Path\\")
output_file = (output_dir / "Token2290newsML.txt")

news_dir = Path("\\Path\\")
news_file = (news_dir / "2290newsML.txt")

tagged_dir = Path("\\Path\\")
tagged_file = (tagged_dir / "tagged2290newsML.txt")

file = open(news_file, "r")
data = file.readlines()

f = open(tagged_file, "w")

def process_content():
    try:
        for i in data:
            words = wt(i)
            pprint.pprint(words)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
            pprint.pprint(tagged)
            #f.write("\n".join(tagged))
            f.write(str.join(tagged))

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

process_content()
file.close()
```

Any help will be appreciated

thanks :)

Comment: What is the output (summarised if too long) of  `pprint.pprint(tagged)`? `str.join()` operates on a sequence of strings, but `tagged` appears to be a sequence of tuples. Possibly you need to flatten the list before joining.

Comment: Check the variable `tagged`. It should be a `list` of `str`s.

Comment: Also, when calling `str.join()` directly you need to pass the join string as the first parameter, i.e. `str.join('\n', tagged)`. But note that you will then get the same exception.

Comment: @mhawke the ouput is ['If']
[('If', 'IN')]
descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'. How would i go about the latter part of your comment?

Comment: @mhawke yes i just tried that and i did receive the same exception

Comment: @mshsayem could you explain what you mean by a list of strs? I know my file contains normal sentences.

Comment: `nltk.pos_tag()` returns a list of tuples. What is your desired output?

Comment: my desired output is to read from a txt file which contains a large amount of text and write new file with POS_Tags of former file. i.e. i would read`news_file` and and then `nltk.pos_tag()` the words to a new file`tagged_file`. hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nltk.pos_tag()`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.pos_tag) returns a list of 2-tuples. The first element of each tuple is the word, the second a part of speech tag corresponding to the word. For example:

```
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag('This is a test'.split())
>>> tagged
[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('a', 'DT'), ('test', 'NN')]
```

Assuming that you would like to write each word and its tag per line:

```
with open(tagged_file, 'w') as f:
    for pair in tagged:
        print(' '.join(pair), file=f)
```

This would create a file containing:

```
This DT
is VBZ
a DT
test NN
```

You can alter the file format as required.

Comment: I tried using the above logic into my code but i get a similar error as before `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`

Comment: Try using the code that I show. You are passing a list to `write` - that's not going to work. What _exactly_ do you want to end up in the output file?

Comment: I want the output you have ie 'word tag' either in line or on separate lines

Comment: right now I can replicate the above result ie printing to the console the word and tag of each word in the file but the problem occurs when i try to save the input to a new file

Comment: What problem? You have to say what the problem is. Why don't you just use `print(' '.join(pair), file=f)` as I show above? This will write to the output file each word and tag per line.

Comment: I have said the problems in the original question - same ones are coming after i use your code to write to a file. your code works if i dont need to write to a different file.My goal is to read from a file (i can share it if you want), tag words in the file and save the words and tags to another file. i can do the first 2 of those steps but not the third one for some reason.

Comment: Are you still using `write()`? The original question mentions problems using `file.write()`, but my code does not use `write()` it uses `print()` with a `file` argument. The `file` argument is the open output file. It will not print to console, it will print to the file specified. Maybe you can update the question with the code that you are now running, and any error messages/exceptions that you are getting.

Comment: yep after altering it to read from a file rather than a hardcoded string: the print function works but it tags each letter eg `T NN; h NN; i NN; s N` on each line rather than `This NN`